# why does python say it cant find the path specified when it made the path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this program yesterday because I am using py2exe, so what this program does is it zips up the folder created by py2exe and names it to app4export so I can send it to my friends. I also added in where if i already have a zip file called app4export then it deletes it before hand, it worked yesterday but now today I get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\severna\\Desktop\\Non_Test_Python_Files\\app4export'
```

but python made this location so I dont get why it cant find it later?

```
import os
import zipfile
import shutil

def zip(src, dst):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile("%s.zip" % (dst), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    abs_src = os.path.abspath(src)
    for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for filename in files:
            absname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            arcname = absname[len(abs_src) + 1:]
            print('zipping %s as %s' % (os.path.join(dirname, filename),
                                        arcname))
            zf.write(absname, arcname)
    zf.close()

source=r"C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files\dist"
destination=r"C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files\app4export"

shutil.rmtree(str(destination))

try:
    zip(str(source), str(destination))
    shutil.rmtree(str(source))

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Source cannot be zipped as it does not exist!")
```

Comment: Where do you create the path?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're running? At the moment the only line that can throw that error is the `shutil.rmtree` line (the rest are in the `try` and the error would be hidden) and that is using a different path (has .zip on the end).

Comment: Rather than messing around with `r''` or  `'\\'`, you can use the fact Windows can handle `'/'` as a path separator. This will remove one possible problem from the equation.

Comment: sorry old code from an attempt to fix will edit now

Comment: @JohnColeman that didnt work mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after discussion with Cleared I found out that I needed i file extension because it was a file and `shutil.rmtree` doesnt remove files it removes directories so I need to use this code instead

```
os.remove(str(destination)+".zip")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates the file `C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files\app4export.zip`, but you try to remove the directory `C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files\app4export`

So just before the `try`-block you have

```
shutil.rmtree(str(destination))
```

which will throw an FileNotFoundError if the path do not exist. And when you hit that line of code, you still havent created the path. The reason it might have worked yesterday was that you mayby had that path.

Comment: the path is there, i am looking right at the zipfile

Comment: I dont belive you :) Go to the directory using the command-promt, do a `dir` and post your result.

Comment: Are you sure that the directory `C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files\app4export` exists? (And i am NOT talking about the file `C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files\app4export.zip`)

Comment: want me to copy and paste the whole thing?

Comment: No, you can skip the unrelevant path. Just post the lines that tells you that you have a DIRECTORY name app4export

Comment: `C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is you dont need to know
 Directory of C:\Users\severna\Desktop\Non_Test_Python_Files

15/12/2016  13:24    <DIR>          .
15/12/2016  13:24    <DIR>          ..
07/12/2016  14:10    <DIR>          .idlerc
13/12/2016  10:40               526 anagram creator.py
15/12/2016  13:24        13,033,051 app4export.zip
15/12/2016  09:06             8,264 brickbreaker.py
21/10/2016  15:04               504 clock.py`

Comment: You DO NOT have a directory/folder named app4export. You only have a FILE called app4export.zip. Therefore you can not remove the DIRECTORY name app4export, because it does not exist.

Comment: so should i use `os.remove` instead?